# Video player issue in flutter (iOS)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am using the latest flutter video player plugin (video_player: ^2.0.2). I am getting the following issue when video playing on an iOS device or simulator, but in Andriod, it is coming fine. should I pass any extra controls to the video player when playing video in iOS?
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71299

There is an issue open on github.
I also have the same issue and don't know how to solve it.
Let me know if you did fix it! ^^